# calling function containing `$http.get()` on button press

Tags: http, angularjs, angularjs-service

calling function containing `$http.get()`

```
$scope.storeDb = function() {

    $scope.url = '/some';
    $http({method: 'GET', url: $scope.url}).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

        console.log(data);
        alert(status);

    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

      alert('error is ' + status);

    });
  }
```

I'm calling function from `ng-click`

```
<input type="submit", value='ask', ng-click='storeDb()'/>
```

The alert message is `error is 0`

Comment: See your browser console log and network tab, for errors or incorrect url.

Comment: use browser console to inspect request...need a lot more detail than what's given

Comment: working on it. let me get back.

Comment: @Chandermani did some diagnostics. still can't get it. There is an error but status is `0`

Comment: @charlietfl did some diagnostics. still can't get it. There is an error but status is 0

Comment: http status 0 means not connected to internet...that doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as much as i believe that jkschneider is right and it seems you do have an error and debugging it should help you find the problem, may i point 2 mistakes please :)

1st is the misuse of th $http.get, it should look like this

```
$http({
    method: 'GET', url: '/someUrl'}).
      success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // this callback will be called asynchronously
        // when the response is available
      }).
      error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
      });
```

can be also like $http.get().success().error();

see here http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http

second of all you should use the MVVM/MVC way to get/update data in your app (i.e. you need to have a model), otherwise you might get into some other problems. i wrote a short tutorial about it with full code examples http://bresleveloper.blogspot.co.il/2013/08/breslevelopers-angularjs-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

Add another function to the `then` handler to handle the error condition, and debug into or log the output.

Comment: did some diagnostics. still can't get it. There is an error but status is 0